# Batch File to execute all .exe in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a batch script that will run all .exe files in a folder. This must include subfolders.

I am running windows 7, and the batch file is stored in the root folder

I have tried several variations with no success. The two main variations are as follows

```
REM dir *.exe /S /B > tmpFile
REM set /p listVar= < tmpFile
REM del tmpFile

FOR %%F IN (%listVar%) DO %%F
```

=======================================

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%F IN ('dir *.exe /S /B') DO %%F
```

I have looked through several variations on the above methods but none work. The top version (which I would like to avoid) only reads in one line from the file. The Bottom version outputs an unmodified "dir" command in the prompt window.

Ultimately I would like help identifying how to solve this issue without the need for a temp file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"
```

This will start all the executable files under the current folder and subfolders. Change the reference to the current folder (`"."`) to your needs.

Comment: That did it thanks. I have modified this down to

for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa

As i would like this to fire in serial (29GB of installers over 19 installers)

Answer (score 0):

```
for %1 in (%USERPROFILE%\*.exe) do "%1"
```

This will start all executables in your user folder. Of course, that includes installers and stuff like that, and you probably don't want to reinstall all your apps, so replace `%USERPROFILE%` with the directory you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important caveat to MC NDs solution.  First if you run that script as an administrator, the home directory defaults to C:\Windows\System32 even if the script is located elsewhere. Attempting to run every script from that location will have a detrimental effect on your system and potentially cause you to need to reinstall windows (ask me how I know... and thank god for test VMs and checkpoints) You should prefix that code with

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
```

This changes the working directory to wherever the file is located.

So the script would be:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"
```

I'd even go so far as to recommend taking the directory as an argument.