# How to run all exe file from one folder/subdolders one by one

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am currently using the following command from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139456/batch-file-to-execute-all-exe-in-a-folder):

```
for /r "\VC++ Redist" %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"
```

and tried this command from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537911/run-all-exe-file-from-one-folder-one-by-one)

```
for %%f in (*.exe) do start /wait %%f
```

but whenever I use the command, the error [pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fib3E.png).

> Windows cannot find specified folder. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

**EDIT:**

I just solved my question using this command:

```
for /r "\VC++ Redist" %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa
```

Comment: Try moving the `""` marks over to here: `\"VC++ Redist"`

Comment: I just solved my question using this command:

for /r "\VC++ Redist" %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa

Comment: @pudding Please post your solution as an answer. [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are meant for other things here. One more thing: You should include the error message as text in the question to make it searchable.

Comment: ooppps! noted @Melebius

Comment: @pudding Not a part of the question but an **answer**.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer so people knows the question is solved.

---

```
for /r "\VC++ Redist" %%a in (*.exe) do %%~fa
```

This works, but I'd prefer using `start`. Using `start` gives you the following abilities:

- Window title
- Window size
- Process priority
- Process affinity
- `WAIT` function
- `NODE` control

Another thing is quote - I'm not sure if your VC++ Redist's `exe` files come with space or not, so as a precaution, I would do:

```
"%%~fa"
```

This ensures safety to files with space(this is not the safest method, yet.)